# Find the object by key & value in JSON in case that I don't know the structure of JSON which is single, array or nested deep structure

Tags: javascript, json

There are three types of JSON I can face randomly,

Fist type, object:

`{ "a" : "b", "@type" : "Product" }`

Second type, array:

`[{ "a" : "b", "@type" : "Test" }, { "a" : "b", "@type" : "Product" }]`

Third type, nested object:

`{ "d" : "e", "f" : { "a" : "b", "@type" : "Product" } }`

I'm trying to get the the object, which contains "@type" : "Product", so my desired result would be`[{ "a" : "b", "@type" : "Product" }]` for all of types.

To get this result, in case of second one, I can use `obj.filter(d => d["@type"]=="Product")` and for the first one, made an empty array, `var empty_array = []; empty_array.push(obj)` and then used that same filter as a second one.

However, I don't know the way to get the desired result when the properties are in nested object.

Is there any JSON filter to get a desired result for all of types?

When I used JsonPath, I used `$..[?(@["\x40type"] =="Product"` for deep search in Json, and it works pretty well, however I would like to find the way in Javascript itself.

Many thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the below approach

```js
// This method will return the type of object. In case of array or JSON, it will return array or json instead of object.
function getType(obj) {
  if (typeof obj === 'object') {
     if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
      return 'array';
     }
     return 'json';
  }
  return typeof obj;
}

// This method will return either the required JSON or null.
function getObject(obj) {
  // Check the type if it is JSON.
  if (getType(obj) === 'json') {
    // If the current object has a key named @type, return the object.
    if (Object.keys(obj).includes('@type') && obj['@type'] === 'Product') return obj;
    // Otherise call the method recursively for each value of JSON.
    const values = Object.values(obj);
    for (let i = 0, n = values.length; i < n; ++i) {
      const returnVal = getObject(values[i]);
      // If the value is required JSON, return that value.
      if (returnVal) return returnVal;
    }
  // Check if the type of object is array.
  } else if (getType(obj) === 'array') {
    // Call the function recursively for each value of the array.
    for (let i = 0, n = obj.length; i < n; ++i) {
      const returnVal = getObject(obj[i]);
      // If you get the required JSON, return it.
      if (returnVal) return returnVal;
    }
  }
  // If you didn't get the required JSON, return null.
  return null;
}

var a = { "a" : "b", "@type" : "Product" };
var b = [{ "a" : "b", "@type" : "Test" }, { "a" : "b", "@type" : "Product" }];
var c = { "d" : "e", "f" : { "a" : "b", "@type" : "Product" } };

console.log(getObject(a));
console.log(getObject(b));
console.log(getObject(c));
```

Comment: Please consider adding a comment on how the code you've used has solved OP's question.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and codes :) It returns the object {
  "a": "b",
  "@type": "Test"
} unlike my desired result. I'm learning from your codes and looking for the way to correct :)

Comment: Please find the comments in the snippet.

Comment: Thank you so much. 
Result:
console.log(getObject(a));
{
  "a": "b",
  "@type": "Product"
}
console.log(getObject(b));
{
  "a": "b",
  "@type": "Test"
}
console.log(getObject(c));
{
  "a": "b",
  "@type": "Product"
}
```console.log(getObject(b));``` => results in wrong object. ```if (Object.keys(obj).includes('@type')) return obj;``` I think it should be a pair of "@type"="Product"``` Could you check that line again please? Many many thanks.

Comment: Please find the updated code. Also, if you are satisfied with the answer, mark it as accepted so that others may also get benefit from this.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a concise solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan):

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const d1 = { a: 'b', '@type': 'Product' };
const d2 = [{ a: 'b', '@type': 'Test' }, { a: 'b', '@type': 'Product' }];
const d3 = { d: 'e', f: { a: 'b', '@type': 'Product' } };

const find = (data) => objectScan(['**.@type'], {
  abort: true,
  rtn: 'parent',
  filterFn: ({ value }) => value === 'Product'
})(data);

console.log(find(d1));
// => { a: 'b', '@type': 'Product' }
console.log(find(d2));
// => { a: 'b', '@type': 'Product' }
console.log(find(d3));
// => { a: 'b', '@type': 'Product' }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.7.1"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)